# Javascript description properties, how can i control its position?

Tags: javascript, css, code-snippets

I just have added a Javascript Slideshow, that have a snippet like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                effectsDemo2 = 'rain,stairs,fade';
                var demoSlider_2 = Sliderman.slider({container: 'SliderName_2', width: 700, height: 450, effects: effectsDemo2,
                    display: {
                        autoplay: 3000,
                        loading: {background: '#000000', opacity: 0.5, image: 'img/loading.gif'},
                        buttons: {hide: true, opacity: 1, prev: {className: 'SliderNamePrev_2', label: ''}, next: {className: 'SliderNameNext_2', label: ''}},
                        description: {hide: true, background: '#000000', opacity: 0.4, height: 50, position: 'bottom', },
                        navigation: {container: 'SliderNameNavigation_2', label: '<img src="img/clear.gif" />'}
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

How can i set the "description" attribute, to have position bottom but a little bit on top? I'd like to add something like CSS "top:-10px"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to API reference of Sliderman Slider you cannot add it using javascript. But I think you can use CSS to little bit on top.

This plugin has not added any class to description. So I will suggest to remove background from the Javascript

```
description: {hide: true, background: transparent, opacity: 1, height: 50, position: 'bottom' },
```

There will be class name similar to `.SliderNameDescription`

You need to add margin-top to it. also add background and other styles to CSS

```
.SliderNameDescription {
   margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the quick answer!

In the position: 'bottom' on the snippet, which else can i add? I want my element centered on the middle (vertical and orizzontal).

Comment: can you put the image how you want it ? it will give better idea.